# Python - Webscraping using XPath

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm scraping Google Playstore. I've an HTML text(user's comments) as follow:-

```
<div class="quoted-review">
    <div class="review-text"> <span class="review-title">Awesome :)</span> Trying to learn some basic Lithuanian and pictures are very helpful. I'd love to learn more from who created this app.. &amp;lt;3
        <div class="paragraph-end details-light"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract the complete text inside class `quoted-review` using XPath, ie *Awesome :). Trying to learn some basic Lithuanian and pictures are very helpful. I'd love to learn more from who created this app.. &lt;3*.

Following are my xPath

1)     `//div[@class='quoted-review review-text']/span[@class='review-title']/text()|//div[@class='quoted-review review-text']/text()`

yields a list

```
[
'Awesome :)' , 
'Trying to learn some basic Lithuanian and pictures are very helpful. I'd love to learn more from who created this app..'
]
```

I want both of them as one item. 
**PS: Please do not advice me to concatenate index 0 and 1 using a for loop. I want them to extract them as one directly using Xpath.**

2)     `//div[@class='review-text']/text()`
yields only

```
[
'Trying to learn some basic Lithuanian and pictures are very helpful. I'd love to learn more from who created this app..'
]
```

*Awesome :)* is missed.

I'm able to get it through BeautifulSoup using `soup.select('.quoted-review')[1].getText()` directly as one, but not using Xpath.

What wrong am I doing?

Comment: What do you use to execute the XPath, `lxml`?

Answer (score 1):

In XPath version 1.0 (version that `lxml` implements), you can call XPath `string()` function to return effective string value of an element like so :

```
string(//div[@class='review-text'])
```

Notice that in case the inner XPath returns multiple elements, only the first will be considered. To support multiple elements correctly you'll need to incorporate some python codes, for example :

```
result = [div.xpath('string()') for div in \
            root.xpath('//div[@class='review-text']')]
```

Just for your information, XPath 2.0 supports invoking `string()` after path separator so you can do this using pure XPath :

```
//div[@class='review-text']/string()
```